x not aligned with the geometric form
This is from a exercise I'm solving for my code class, I am trying to solve it without any help but tI'm not understanding how to solve this issue. GPT can't help me neither because they print stuff diferently so it's always wrong.
output:
x           x
x            x
x             x
x x x x x x x x x

output wanted:
x         x
x           x
x             x
x x x x x x x x x

code:
numeroRecebido = 5

def EsqSide(numeroRecebidoL, numeroRecebidoC, i):
    numeroRecebidoL = numeroRecebidoC - 3
    while i <= numeroRecebidoL:
        i = i + 1
        print("x", end=" ")
        spc = 0
        while(spc <= numeroRecebidoC + i):
            spc = spc + 1
            print(" ", end="")
        print("", end=" ")
        print("  x")

def baseBottom(numeroRecebido, i):
    if(numeroRecebido >= 5):
        numeroRecebido = numeroRecebido * 2
        numeroRecebido  = numeroRecebido - 2
        while(i <= numeroRecebido):
            i = i + 1
            print("x", end=" ")

    else:
        numeroRecebido = numeroRecebido * 2
        while(i <= numeroRecebido):
            i = i + 1
            print("x", end=" ")

EsqSide(numeroRecebidoL=numeroRecebido, numeroRecebidoC=numeroRecebido, i=0)
baseBottom(numeroRecebido, i=0)


It's fixed, sorry about that

you need to add 2 instead of 1, because you need to add one position and 1 space.

I've done that in every way I thinked of, the code is executable, execute on your PC and try it out please

ahahah, my man, try that out to see what are you trying so say....

change i = i + 1 to i = i + 2 in EsqSide

that "fixes" it but it deletes one of the sides, it now has 2 instead of 3

You have a number of little inconsistencies, but they are enough to display the last x in a wrong place:

you start with spc = 0 while the initial x has used one position
you increment i before displaying the line when you should do that after
you only add one single space with print(" ", end="") while the bottom line has 2 positions per element (one space and one x)
you have added a extraneous print("", end=" ") probably as an inefficent attempt to fix the wrong position of the last x

Here is a fixed version:
def EsqSide(numeroRecebidoL, numeroRecebidoC, i):
    numeroRecebidoL = numeroRecebidoC - 3
    while i <= numeroRecebidoL:
        print("x", end=" ")
        spc = 1
        while(spc < numeroRecebidoC + i):
            spc = spc + 1
            print(" ", end=" ")
        print("x")
        i = i + 1

With it, I could get:
x         x
x           x
x             x
x x x x x x x x x 

